# Simple password check with limited retries

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, passwords

I'm trying to do a simple password check with limited retries.

If user keys in wrong password, program prompts to try again (3 retries).
After 3 failed retries, program prompts user has reached maximum retries.
If User keys in correct password, program will "grant access".

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
pssw = '' 
attempt = 0   

print('Please key in your password.') 

while (pssw != "remember") and (attempt < 3):    
    pssw = input()  
    attempt = attempt + 1

print ('No that is not correct. Try again.')

if attempt == 3:
    print ('Sorry you have reached maximum number of attempts')
    break

if (pssw == "remember"):
    print('Access Granted!')
```

Problem #1

Expectation: After keying in the correct password "Remember", program should print output "Access Granted"

But program output:

```
3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06) 
Please key in your password.
remember
No that is not correct. Try again.
Access Granted!
```

Problem #2

Expectation: After keying in the correct password "Remember" on the last try, program should print output "Access Granted"

But program output:

```
Please key in your password.
test
No that is not correct. Try again.
test
No that is not correct. Try again.
remember
No that is not correct. Try again.
Sorry you have reached maximum number of attempts
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You always execute `print ('No that is not correct. Try again.')`. Actually your recorded output does not match the code you have posted.

Comment: If you need some help you should update the question so that the code and the program output match each other. Then you can correctly state how your expectations are not met by the output. And then we can help you.

Comment: Thanks i figured out from the post below the flow was wrong. Expectation was that program should execute `'No that is not correct. Try again` on the first 2 wrong retries. The last wrong retry should execute `Sorry you have reached maximum number of attempts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just explain your errors because someone posted another code approach.
I think it's important that you understand your erros and do not just copy another code.

First, the line `break` is incorrect because a break cant be outside a loop, use `sys.exit()` instead.

**Problem #1**:

If you enter the right password your program will exit the loop and execute the next statements:

```
print ('No that is not correct. Try again.')

if attempt == 3:
    print ('Sorry you have reached maximum number of attempts')
    break

if (pssw == "remember"):
    print('Access Granted!')
```

So it will print "No that is not correct. Try again.".

Check if attempt is equal to 3. It isn't because you entered the right password at the first attempt.

Check if password is equal to "remember". It is, so program will print "Access granted".

**Problem #2**:

Your second output is incoherent with the code you posted.
Normal output for the code you posted is:

```
Please key in your password.
test
test
remember 
No that is not correct. Try again.
Sorry you have reached maximum number of attempts
```

This is the normal output for the code you posted, but it's wrong anyway.

It's because if tou type an incorrect password, the loop will just continue and thus ask again for your password without printing anything.

Comment: Thank you for explaining on what i did wrong and highlighting the use of `sys.exit()` instead of `break`  i have managed to successfully edit the code and works as expected.